# How to split and get value in string

Tags: javascript, split

Hi i have a string like `"john ka [12345678]"` and `"james james [12121212]"` etc.
How to split sting and get value inside "[]".
Expected output is `12345678` and `12121212` like this

I tried split method.

```
string1 = "john ka [12345678]"
string2 = "james james [12121212]"
// etc.
```

Output should be 
12345678 and 12121212

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a task for "splitting". How did you come to that solution? What other string manipulation/parsing solutions have you looked at?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get only number in square brackets, you can use this:

```
string1.match(/(?<=\[)[0-9]+(?=\])/g)[0]
```

This will help you even if you have any other text in square brackets, like:

```
var string1 = "john [abc] ka [12345678]";
```

Output will be: `12345678`

**Edit:** 
As lookbehind is only available in the browsers that support ECMA2018, adding another solution without using lookbehind:

```
var string1 = "john [abc] ka [12345678]";
new RegExp(/(?:\[)([0-9]+)(?=\])/, 'g').exec(string1)[1];
```

Comment: "this will help you even if you have any other text in square brackets", true, but this will pose a problem if he has numbers outside of square brackets that he doesn't want to match. OP's asking to get things inside brackets, and you've answered how to get the first number of the string.

Comment: As @Aaron correctly pointed out, I've modified the regex a little using positive and negative lookahead.

Comment: You'd want a positive lookbehind as the first lookaround, currently you're checking that the next character isn't an opening bracket, but you're already checking just afterward that it's a number. Check `"don't match 01234]".match(/(?!\[)[0-9]+(?=\])/)` ; also noticed you're passing `string1` as the second argument which represents flags.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = string1.substring(string1.indexOf( '[' ) +1, string1.indexOf( ']' ));
```

Comment: This is the simplest and most straight-forward approach, since it does not incur (or need) the overhead of regular expressions. You're searching for exactly two specific, exact characters, so why add in all that overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var matches = string1.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
```

This should returns an array of all the strings between square brackets, for the first occurrence just second item in the resulting array.

```
var value = matches[1];
```

### Edit

Other answers are pointing to the use of split and substring, this will work however if regular expressions are available they should be used in this situation as you are looking to match a pattern "[" as the start and "]" as the end. This approach is more robust due to it intelligently searching for the position of the desired string, rather than assuming it.

Comment: it returns array of the match values only if there is global flag(`/g`). in your case [0] has the whole match, and [1] the first group

Comment: You can use `[\w\W]+`  instead of `.*` to take care of newline too.

Comment: @CodeManiac Or more apropriately in this context, `[^]]*` (which also includes newlines but excludes closing brackets, removing the need for a reluctant quantifier)

Answer (score 0):

## Two Ways to Extract Numbers

The demo has two ways of extract numbers between brackets: `[...]`

1. Regex pattern and String method `.replace()`

> ```
> str.replace(/.+?\[([0-9]+?)\]/g, '$1 ')
> ```

2. Regex pattern, Array methods `.split()` and `.filter()`

> ```
> str.split(/\[|\]/);
>
> arr.filter(function(num) {
>     return parseInt(num, 10);
> });
> ```

---

### Demo

```js
var str = `john ka [12345678] and james james [12121212]`;

/*Regex replace()===================*/

var rgx = /.+?\[([0-9]+?)\]/g;

var R1 = str.replace(rgx, '$1 ');

console.log(R1);

/*Array split() and filter()========*/

var arr = str.split(/\[|\]/);

var R2 = arr.filter(function(num) {
  return parseInt(num, 10);
});

console.log(R2);
```